# Is glGetUniformLocation necessary

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am following tutorials on both Youtube and online and they all say to use glGetUniformLocation to get the uniform location of the uniform in the shader. But what if you know the index of the uniform location to begin with, it saves one draw call at the start of program and you can just hard code in a value.

I'm asking specifically about whether its necessary due to being able to hard code in the value. Not the new features of openGL that gives you the ability to get the same result.

In my program I tried inputting the following. `glUniform4f(0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3);` and it works!. Its linking to the first uniform in the shader.

I've tried searching "importance of glGetUniformLocation" and "Is glGetUniformLocation necessary" in stackoverflow and found no one asking the same question as I am. As a new openGl learning, reading through the openGL books I can't seem to find any explanation of this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until GLSL gained the [ability to specify a uniform's location in the text itself](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Explicit_uniform_location), you needed to call `glGetUniformLocation` (or an equivalent) at least once for any particular program, for any particular uniform within that program which you wanted to manipulate. You could cache that value, either in specific variables or in data structures. But you needed to call it at least once.

However, once a program could specify the location of its uniforms, there was no longer a reason to do this. After all, the shader must specify the correct name that your `glGetUniformLocation` call looks for, right? What is the difference between the shader specifying a name and the shader specifying a number? They're just identifiers representing some conceptual meaning within that program; one is a string, the other a number. And the shader has to use the correct identifier, the one which matches the thing your code expects to find.

So if you have the ability to specify locations in your shader, you should just do that and forgo any `glGetUniformLocation` usage.